# Adding to an element in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, storage

At the moment inside the  class I have ArrayList which the objects are stored in when they are added to the club. I also have a integer which would be auto incremented once a object has been added to the ArrayList. However, I am unsure how I would be able to add the registration ID with the player object in the ArrayList.

Comment: how does your Player class look like? does Player class have a property int registrationId ?

Comment: What does your `Player` class look like? If I can make an assumption that `Player.setRegID(int)` is defined, then it would be straightforward.

Comment: there is no need for your model to increment the registration id by yourself.
every time you add a new object into players, the arraylist size will be automatically incremented. you can get the size with players.size();

if you want to ask, which id a current player object has, call players.indexOf(player).

Comment: I assume `Players` can be part of multiple `Clubs`, in which case it doesn't make sense to store the registration ID in the `Player` class, unless the method is something like `Player.setRegId(Club c, int id)`.

Comment: I like @andreasg's solution as an alternative to what I posted. It's clean and straightforward. The only potential issue is if `Player`s can leave a `Club`, then you'll need a separate structure to keep track of `Players` who are no longer valid (removing them from the list would change all the ID numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not completely clear from your description what exactly you are trying to do, so I am guessing something like this:

```
public synchronized void registerPlayer(Player p)
{
    p.setRegistrationId(registrationID++);
    players.add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a `Map`, which associates the individual ID with the particular player, as a key-value pair, instead of a `List`:

```
public class Club
{

    private String clubName;
    private int registrationID;
    private Map<Player, Integer> players;

    /**
     * Create a club with given club name.
     */
    public Club(String clubName)
    {
        players = new HashMap<Player, Integer>();
        this.clubName = clubName;
        registrationID = 1;
    }

    public void registerPlayer(Player p)
    {
        // check if player is already in the club:
        if (!players.containsKey(p)) {
            players.put(p, new Integer(registrationID));
            // increment ID counter:
            registrationID++;
        }
    }

    public void listAll () 
    {
        for (Player p : players.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another class:

```
public class Registration() {
    private Player player;
    private String registrationId;

    public Registration(Player p) {
        // Assign p to player
        // Generate the registration ID
    }
}
```

Then just have `ArrayList<Registration> registrations` to hold all these. Your `listAll()` method would then need to reference `i.getNext().getPlayer()` to perform the same action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing Player has a field for ID which you want to set after adding it to the arraylist?

If you know the index of the Player, just fetch the object with the `get` method and set the ID. If you don't have the index, you'll have to loop through the arraylist to find your object.